# Performance implications of using crontab to automate numerous DB tasks?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql

I think I'm going to use crontab to run a bunch of scripts that will:

- close all expired posts
- accept uncontested disputes
- add interest charges
- email out invoices
- send "about to expire" notifications

I want the expired stuff to be removed pretty shortly after the event occurs, so I'm thinking about writing one script that will run and check for all these various dates every 5 to 15 minutes. Can I expect any troubles doing this? At what number of "posts" might I start seeing performance issues? Are we talking thousands or millions?

Comment: "troubles"?  What are you worried about?  Mainframes have been working like this with scheduled jobs for decades.  It's normal, standard, typical, ordinary design.  Do you have any volume information on this "all expired"?  "uncontented"?  With no numbers, it's impossible to suggest anything.

Comment: @S.Lott: Didn't realize this was "normal" design. That puts me at ease :) Wasn't sure if this was even the right way to go about things. Don't have any numbers yet, as we haven't launched. I expect about 15K "posts" and 250K invoices to be added each year, and they're never deleted. Disputes will hopefully be much more rare.

Comment: Yep it's called batch processing.

Comment: If you're doing anything with the "posts" and there's only 15k per year...I wouldn't worry about any performance issues with them on reasonably modern hardware for quite some time.  Unless you're doing something pretty crazy with invoices, you shouldn't have issues with 250k per year for a good number of years.  This is shooting from the hip though, it all depends on hardware and what *exactly* you're doing.

Comment: @rfusca: Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing anything with the "posts" and there's only 15k per year...I wouldn't worry about any performance issues with them on reasonably modern hardware for quite some time. Unless you're doing something pretty crazy with invoices, you shouldn't have issues with 250k per year for a good number of years. This is shooting from the hip though, it all depends on hardware and what exactly you're doing